# $(\frac{n}{n+1})^n$ converges to $0$, so why is it converge to 1 when $n=999999....$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

[image: Getting confused by the result when placing n=999999999999999999]

I hope to find out if it's an issue with my calculator or something more interesting.

Comment: Are you sure about that? $\lim_{x\to\infty} \left({x \over x + 1}\right)^x = \lim_{x\to\infty} \left(1-{1\over x}\right)^x = \dots$.

Comment: Why do you think $(\frac {n}{n+1})^n $ converges to $0$.  That's simply wrong.

Comment: @fleablood because my college book claims that.

Comment: Reread your textbook.  I bet you it is claiming $\lim_{n\to 0} (\frac {n}{n+1})^n = 0$.  So if you punch in $x= 0.0000000001$ you will get something close to zero.  But $\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac {n}{n+1})^n = 1$.

Comment: Oops.  You book is just wrong.

Comment: @MorHaham You are testing the calculator to its limits of accuracy in terms of the way it has been programmed. That has gone wrong here. It's common with a lot of calculators...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right)^n = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right)^n}} = \frac{1}{\left( \frac{n+1}{n} \right)^n} = \frac{1}{\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n}
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: That's a nice approach

Comment: @imranfat thanks, I once saw this in an undergraduate lecture on basic analysis and remembered it for whatever reason... ;-)

Answer (score 7):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n= e^{-1}\ne0.$$
Any evidence against this from your calculator is likely to be due
to inaccurate floating point arithmetic.